# Fill array with values from different other arrays from different lengths

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, while-loop

I'm trying to do the following:
For examns, I have x chairs and x pupils. The chairs could varie and the people could varie per class and year.

Example: There are 112 chairs and 102 pupils. I need to fill the chairs so that pupils of the same year are not next to each other.

The chairs are not always in rows, so the places could varie too.

What I did:

- I've got two arrays with columns of chairs: $chairs1: A, D, F,... and $chairs2=B, E, G,... (I allready filtered row C wich is completely empty for example) This way, I can put the third year in array 1 and the fourth in array 2. That way, the pupils from the first year are not next to each other
- I have one array with the number of pupils per year. So that $numberofpupilsperyear[1] = number of pupils in the first year.
- I have 7 other arrays, one for each year with this text: $class-$examn-$classnumber. Fyi: 3Wb-English-1, 3Wb-English-2, 3Wb-English-3,...
- All chairs are numberd from A1 to R19. But not all chairs exists in every place. So I have an array $allchairs[] with the existing chairs
  in that particular room to check if the chair exists.

Now I need to fill the biggest chairarray with the biggest yeararray. 
So if $chairs1 has 80 chairs, and year 2 has the most pupils, the filling should begin in $chairs1, with the pupils from year 2, going on with the second most pupils per year.

What I have untill now, plus all of the above.

```
if($chairs1 >= $chairs2)    
{
    //fill chairs1
    $currentnumber = 1;
    $counter=0;
    while ($currentnumber < 20) 
    {   
        foreach($chairs1 as $key => $value) 
        {   
            //make coordinate of the chair
            $currentletter = $value;
            //check if chair exists
            if(in_array($currentletter.$currentnumber, $allchairs)) 
            {
                //Fill this place with a pupil like for example: 3Wb-English-1

                //But I'm a bit stuck here...
                //I was trying with the following
                $biggestyear = $number_of_students[$counter];
                echo "biggestyear: ".$biggestyear;
                ${$classlist.$biggestyear};

            }
        }
        $currentnumber++;
    }
    //now fill chairs2
    else
    {
        //fill chairs2 first and then chairs1
    }
```

I hope you understand what I mean... And if I need to rethink the whole pseudocode in the beginning, please provide some hints.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm correct in a nutshell:

What you try to accomplish is given a grid of chairs (whether or not the grid is equally sized), assign pupils based on class, so same class isn't next to eachother.

Chair numbers / names, class numbers and exams are all "metadata" in this case and do not add anything towards the real problem.

So, I would start off by first designing the Grid of chairs, where it must be possible to block off chairs (i.e. assign "not available" for example).

Since im better with code than words:

```
$grid = new ChairGrid(6, 18);

// set non-available chairs
$grid->get(2,5)->assigned = 'NA';
$grid->get(1,10)->assigned = 'NA';

// change names as you wish
$grid->get(0,12)->name = 'BG1';

print($grid);

$pupils = array(
    1 => 20,
    2 => 30,
    3 => 20,
    4 => 20,
    5 => 20
);

// returns left-overs
var_dump($grid->assign($pupils));

print($grid);
```

Chargrid class:

```
class ChairGrid {
    private $sizeX;
    private $sizeY;
    private $grid;

    public function __construct($sizeX, $sizeY) {
        $this->grid = array();

        $this->sizeX = $sizeX;
        $this->sizeY = $sizeY;

        for($x = 0; $x < $sizeX; $x++) {
            $this->grid[$x] = array();
            for($y = 0; $y < $sizeY; $y++) {
                $chair = new Chair(chr(ord('A') + $y) . $x, $x, $y);
                $this->grid[$x][$y] = $chair;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $x
     * @param $y
     *
     * @return Chair
     */
    public function get($x, $y) {
        if (isset($this->grid[$x][$y])) {
            return $this->grid[$x][$y];
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function assign($pupils) {
        $retval = array();

        foreach($pupils as $class=>$number) {
            $retval[$class] = 0;

            $column = 0;
            $row = -1;
            for($i=0; $i < $number;$i++) {
                $done = false;
                while(!$done) {
                    $row++;
                    if ($row >= $this->sizeY) {
                        $row = 0;
                        $column++;
                        if ($column >= $this->sizeX) {
                            $retval[$class]++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    $chair = $this->get($column, $row);
                    if ($chair instanceof Chair && $chair->assigned === null) {
                        // var_dump($chair->getX() . ',' . $chair->getY() . ' --?--> '.$class);

                        $chairLeft = $this->get($chair->x - 1, $chair->y);
                        $chairRight = $this->get($chair->x + 1, $chair->y);
                        if ($chairRight === null) {
                            $chairFirst = $this->get(0, $chair->y);
                            if ($chairLeft === null || $chairLeft->assigned !== $class) {
                                // assign
                                $chair->assigned = $class;
                                $done = true;
                            }
                            else if ($chairFirst->assigned !== $class) {
                                $prev = null;
                                for($moveColumn = $this->sizeX - 1; $moveColumn >= 0; $moveColumn--) {
                                    $current = $this->get($moveColumn, $row);
                                    if ($current->assigned !== 'NA') {
                                        if ($prev instanceof Chair) {
                                            $prev->assigned = $current->assigned;
                                        }

                                        $prev = $current;
                                    }
                                }
                                // we cannot assign, so check "right" in first column, if we can assign, shift column
                                $chairFirst->assigned = $class;
                                $done = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (($chairLeft === null || $chairLeft->assigned !== $class) && ($chairRight === null || $chairRight->assigned !== $class)) {
                            $chair->assigned = $class;
                            $done = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $retval;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        $string = array();
        for($y = 0; $y < $this->sizeY; $y++) {
            $tmp = '';
            for($x = 0; $x < $this->sizeX; $x++) {
                $tmp .= '[' . str_pad($this->grid[$x][$y]->name, 3, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT) . '|' . str_pad($this->grid[$x][$y]->assigned, 3, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT) . ']';
            }
            $string[] = $tmp;
        }

        return implode("\n", $string) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Simple chair class:

```
class Chair {
    public $name;
    public $assigned = null;

    public $x;
    public $y;

    public function __construct($name, $x, $y) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's correct, if I'm reading your comment. Since I'm not that good with code than words (I'm just an amateur PHP-coder and not familiair with functions. Shame on me!), I'm going to try(and error) and adapt this code to do exactly as I want and come back to it. Nevertheless, this answer seems logic and helpfull. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I Made this code with some random data to test it. You can just use the fill_seats function and add the right arguments in it.

```
$chairs1 = range(1, 15); //Make 5 arrays of chairs
$chairs2 = range(16, 40);
$chairs3 = range(41, 60);
$chairs4 = range(61, 68);
$chairs5 = range(69, 100);

$chairs = array($chairs1,$chairs2,$chairs3,$chairs4,$chairs5); // add them to 1 array as subarrays

// Fill 5 classes with students
for($i = 1;$i <= 10; $i++){
  $year3[] = '3Wb-English-' . $i;
  if($i<8){
    $year2[] = '2Wb-English-' . $i;
  }
  if($i<7){
    $year1[] = '1Wb-English-' . $i;
  }
  if($i<9){
    $year5[] = '5Wb-English-' . $i;
  }
  if($i<6){
    $year4[] = '4Wb-English-' . $i;
  }
}

$years = array($year1,$year2,$year3,$year4,$year5); // same as chairs


//sort the array according to the number of items in the array (biggest first)
usort($years, 'sort_by_count');
usort($chairs, 'sort_by_count');

// Remove some chairs from all of them
$all_chairs = range(1,100);
unset($all_chairs[5]);
unset($all_chairs[16]);
unset($all_chairs[44]);
unset($all_chairs[65]);
unset($all_chairs[37]);

// loop over them and fill in the seats (you can do this now because arrays are already sorted by count)
foreach($years as $k => $y){
  $filled_seats[] = fill_seats($chairs[$k],$y,$all_chairs);
}

function fill_seats($chairs, $students, $all_chairs){
  $i = 0;
  foreach($chairs as $chair){
    // Seat not available
    if(!in_array($chair,$all_chairs)){
      $filled_chairs[$chair] = 'N/A';
      continue;
    }
    // Still some students left
    if(isset($students[$i])){
      $filled_chairs[$chair] = $students[$i];
    // No students left, leave them empty
    }else{ 
      $filled_chairs[$chair] = '';
    }
    $i++;
  }
  return $filled_chairs;
}

function sort_by_count($a, $b) {
    $a = count($a);
    $b = count($b);
    return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a > $b) ? -1 : 1);
}
```

result print_r($filled_seats):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [69] => 3Wb-English-1
            [70] => 3Wb-English-2
            [71] => 3Wb-English-3
            [72] => 3Wb-English-4
            [73] => 3Wb-English-5
            [74] => 3Wb-English-6
            [75] => 3Wb-English-7
            [76] => 3Wb-English-8
            [77] => 3Wb-English-9
            [78] => 3Wb-English-10
            [79] => 
            [80] => 
            [81] => 
            [82] => 
            [83] => 
            [84] => 
            [85] => 
            [86] => 
            [87] => 
            [88] => 
            [89] => 
            [90] => 
            [91] => 
            [92] => 
            [93] => 
            [94] => 
            [95] => 
            [96] => 
            [97] => 
            [98] => 
            [99] => 
            [100] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [16] => 5Wb-English-1
            [17] => N/A
            [18] => 5Wb-English-2
            [19] => 5Wb-English-3
            [20] => 5Wb-English-4
            [21] => 5Wb-English-5
            [22] => 5Wb-English-6
            [23] => 5Wb-English-7
            [24] => 5Wb-English-8
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => N/A
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [41] => 2Wb-English-1
            [42] => 2Wb-English-2
            [43] => 2Wb-English-3
            [44] => 2Wb-English-4
            [45] => N/A
            [46] => 2Wb-English-5
            [47] => 2Wb-English-6
            [48] => 2Wb-English-7
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
            [51] => 
            [52] => 
            [53] => 
            [54] => 
            [55] => 
            [56] => 
            [57] => 
            [58] => 
            [59] => 
            [60] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1Wb-English-1
            [2] => 1Wb-English-2
            [3] => 1Wb-English-3
            [4] => 1Wb-English-4
            [5] => 1Wb-English-5
            [6] => N/A
            [7] => 1Wb-English-6
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [61] => 4Wb-English-1
            [62] => 4Wb-English-2
            [63] => 4Wb-English-3
            [64] => 4Wb-English-4
            [65] => 4Wb-English-5
            [66] => N/A
            [67] => 
            [68] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: Looks good for 2 classes, but I've got a lot more. There could be as much as 7 different classes in the room. So I'll have to compare each of them with all of the other classes.
And the chairs are numbered A1-Z20, so the pupils are able to find their place.
But I still can use the way the arrays are filled with that function, I guess. I'm going to test this! Thanks!

Comment: @Fl1p As long as your array of chairs is 0 => 'A1' to 519 => 'Z20' it should be ok for the function. Let me find a solution to the other problem.

Comment: @Fl1p Updated code for more classes (for the purpose of the demo I used numbers for the chairs because it's easier to fill more of them). It should work with alphanumeric chairs too.